# How to list me vertex normals to the specified tops?

Tags: three.js

I do animation at which the part of tops moves. Thus lighting starts working incorrectly.  For correct lighting it is necessary to change face.vertexNormals.  At first I thought that it is enough

`geometry.computeVertexNormals();`

But it appeared, it does not absolutely that. 
How to list me topmost vertex normals to the specified tops? 
OR
How to list me the faces containing specified tops?
example [here](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/example_dynamo_plane/)

Here example. But I need not only to see them, and to list and change in the program.

`if (d<50) { var dist = 15 * Math.cos( d/20 - t );
geometry.vertices[i].z = dist; }`

How to list me vertex normals for these tops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plane is upside-down, which causes your vertex normals to point downward.

Set `plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;`.

To see the normals, add

```
vnh = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( plane, 20, 0xff0000, 2 );
scene.add( vnh );
```

to your `init()` function, and in your animation loop call:

```
vnh.update();
```

three.js r.68

Comment: Thanks! But I need not only to see them, and to list and change in the program.

<code>
if (d<50)
    {
 var dist = 15 * Math.cos( d/20 - t );  
 geometry.vertices[i].z =  dist;
    }
</code>

How to list me vertex normals for these tops?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your English. What do you mean by "list me"? What are "tops"? Maybe Google Translate will help you.

Comment: google badly translates ( .
It seems, I was wrong. geometry.computeVertexNormals();  solves all problems.

Comment: You confused me these with the remark: "I think it is OK to call computeFaceNormals(). But vertex normals need to be updated manually using the normalMatrix appropriate for whatever affine transformation you are using on that particular vertex. computeVertexNormals() smooths normals of shared vertices at the corners of your BoxGeometry. Of course, you could say it is a feature, if you want."

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the VertexNormalsHelper. It so quickly works, directly surprisingly =)